# Determination of formula for a 3 independent variable issue

Tags: function, variables, 3d, formula

I have 3 arrays of X, Y and Z. Each have 8 elements. Now for each possible combination of (X,Y,Z) I have a V value.

I am looking to find a formula e.g. V=f(X,Y,Z). Any idea about how that can be done?

Thank you in advance,

Astry

Answer (score 0):

You have a function sampled on a (possibly nonuniform) 3D grid, and want to evaluate the function at any arbitrary point within the volume. One way to approach this (some say the best) is as a multivariate spline evaluation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_interpolation

First, you need to find which rectangular parallelepiped contains the (x,y,z) query point, then you need to interpolate the value from the nearest points. The easiest thing is to use trilinear interpolation from the nearest 8 points. If you want a smoother surface, you can use quadratic interpolation from 27 points or cubic interpolation from 64 points.

For repeated queries of a tricubic spline, your life would be a bit easier by preprocessing the spline to generate Hermite patches/volumes, where your sample points not only have the function value, but also its derivatives (∂/∂x, ∂/∂y, ∂/∂z). That way you don't need messy code for the boundaries at evaluation time.